# Right way of installing Windows 8 and Ubuntu with encrypted file system

Tags: security, disk-encryption

Here is problem. for which I am looking for solution

My Current Installation on laptop and HDD Partition is as follows.

```
500 GB HDD
-- C: 35 GB [Windows 8 Consumer Preview]
-- D: 195 GB
-- E: 195 GB
-- / 37 GB Linux Root [Ubuntu 12.04LTS]
-- swap 3 GB Linux Swap
```

I want to install Windows 8 Release Preview with current Ubuntu installation intact. Also I want to take this opportunity to (learn to) make my system secure. Here are following doubts/quires.

1. How to encrypt windows and ubuntu [at-least /home] partition?
2. If encryption can be done, can I access windows partition(s) from ubuntu.
3. Is there any recomended way of partitioning HDD for windows and user account creation for security purpose.
4. If somethings goes wrong in OS then how to recover data from these encrypted file partitions.
5. Any other possible suggestion for securing system.

[ For this problem I am considering my laptop is being in Vulnerable environment and with highly confidentiality contained in it.]